# Joint pdf of N generally correlated (absolute values of) R.Vs as a joint pdf of (absolute value squared) random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

The joint pdf of $|g_1|,|g_2|,\ldots,|g_N|$ is given by

$P_{|g_1|,|g_2|,\ldots\ldots,|g_N|}(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_N)=$ $$\prod_{
\substack{k=1 \\ \mu_1 \triangleq 0}}^N \frac{2r_k}{\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)} \exp\left(-\frac{r_k^2 + \mu_k^2r_1^2}{\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)} \right) I_0 \left(\frac{2\mu_kr_1r_2}{\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)}\right) $$

where the $k$th correlated fading random variable can be parametrized as
$g_{kl} = \sqrt{1-\mu_k^2} x_{kl} + \mu_{kl} x_{0l} + j\left(\sqrt{1-\mu_k^2} y_{kl} + \mu_{kl}y_{0l} \right), l = 2,\ldots,m,$

where $x_{kl}$ and $y_{kl}$ are independent Gaussian RVs with zero mean and variance $1/2.$

The correlation coefficient, denoted by $0\lt\mu_k\lt1$ is found as $\mu_k = J_0\left(\frac{2\pi(k-1)\alpha}{N-1}\right)$ for $k = 2,\ldots,N,$ where $J_0(\cdot)$ is the zero order Bessel function of the first kind.

I would like to get the joint pdf of $|g_1|^2,|g_2|^2,\ldots,|g_N|^2$.

---

### The above is my original posted question. below is my more precise question

I have $N$ flat fading channels experienced by $N$ ports on a user equipment that are placed closer than the $\lambda/2$ distance meaning there is spatial correlation among them (as given above by the zero order Bessel function) and the amplitudes of the channels are Rayleigh distributed each with pdf $P_{|g_k|}(r) = \frac{2r}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{\sigma^2}},$ for $r \geq 0$ with $E[|g_k|^2]= \sigma^2$. Also the average SNR is defined as $\Gamma = \frac{E[|g_k|^2] E[|x|^2]}{\sigma_\eta^2}.$

The user equipment is such that it can select the best port with the strongest signal, i.e., $|g| = max{(|g_1|,|g_2|,...,|g_N|)}.$ This is equivalent to selection combining technique.

If the instantaneous SNR at any of the $N$ branches is given as $\gamma_i = \frac{A^2|g_i|^2}{N_i}$ where $A$ is the amplitude of the transmitted signal and $N_i$ is the noise spectral density, the selection combiner would choose the branch with the maximum instantaneous SNR for a symbol decision. The output SNR would be equal to
$|\gamma| = max{(|\gamma_1|,|\gamma_2|,...,|\gamma_N|)}.$

In my original question i have a joint pdf of $|g_1|,|g_2|,\ldots,|g_N|$. I wanted a (preferably, in closed form) a joint pdf of $|g_1^2|,|g_2^2|,\ldots,|g_N^2|$ and then wanted to transform that to the joint pdf of $|\gamma_1|,|\gamma_2|,\ldots,|\gamma_N|$

The previous answer that I got helped me to cancel out terms that were the reciprocal of the jacobian which just left me with a product of N exponentials and a product of N zero order modified Bessel functions.

So I  am asking for a transformation of my joint pdf in terms of channel coefficients into joint pdf of snrs.

I Hope the way I posed my question is not confusing for the experts out there whose help I seek. Thank you

Comment: The pdf is probably a big mess — what would you do with it?

Comment: I would like to use that further to find the pdf in terms of SNRs on those channels/ports and then to further multiply with another simple exponential distribution and further do some computation. But this is the first step I am stuck at and I went through IEEE papers related to the matter but could not find a solid hint to help me get my desired pdf.

Comment: I prefer a clearer goal — good luck with the further computation!

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: The OP should not change the question so as to invalidate a valid answer or to require extensive modifications. Also, questions on MathOverflow should be stated in fully mathematical terms. In particular, terms such "user equipment" or "selection combiner" should not be used. Since your modified question is as easy to answer as the original one, I have made an exception and provided an answer to the modified question as well, even though it took a lot of extra typing.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\p\partial\newcommand\ga\gamma$By the [substitution formula for multiple integrals](https://www.global-sci.org/oldweb/jms/freedownload/v50n3/pdf/503-268.pdf), the joint pdf of $|g_1|^2,\dots,|g_N|^2$ is given by
$$P_{|g_1|^2,\dots,|g_N|^2}(s_1,\dots,s_N)=P_{|g_1|,\dots,|g_N|}(s_1^{1/2},\dots,s_N^{1/2})J(s_1,\dots,s_N)$$
for $s_1>0,\dots,s_N>0$,
where
$$J(s_1,\dots,s_N)=\frac1{2^N}\prod_{j=1}^N s_j^{-1/2}$$
is the (here positive) determinant of the (here diagonal) Jacobian matrix
$$\frac{\p(s_1^{1/2},\dots,s_N^{1/2})}{\p(s_1,\dots,s_N)}
:=\Big(\frac{\p(s_i^{1/2})}{\p s_j}\Big)_{i,j=1}^N$$
of the transformation $(s_1,\dots,s_N)\mapsto(s_1^{1/2},\dots,s_N^{1/2})$, which latter is inverse to the transformation $(t_1,\dots,t_N)\mapsto(t_1^2,\dots,t_N^2)$.

So, if you know $P_{|g_1|,\dots,|g_N|}$, it is very easy to get $P_{|g_1|^2,\dots,|g_N|^2}$.

---

The OP has changed the question -- now wanting the joint pdf of $\ga_1,\dots,\ga_N$ instead of the joint pdf of $|g_i|^2,\dots,|g_N|^2$, where $\ga_i=\frac{A^2|g_i|^2}{N_i}$.

By the same substitution formula for multiple integrals,
the joint pdf of $\ga_1,\dots,\ga_N$ is given by
$$P_{\ga_1,\dots,\ga_N}(r_1,\dots,r_N)
=P_{|g_i|^2,\dots,|g_N|^2}(\tfrac{N_1}{A^2}\,r_1,\dots,\tfrac{N_N}{A^2}\,r_n)K=P_{|g_1|,\dots,|g_N|}(\tfrac{N_1^{1/2}}A\,r_i^{1/2},\dots,\tfrac{N_1^{1/2}}A\,r_i^{1/2})J(N_1 r_1/A^2,\dots,N_N r_N/A^2) K$$
for $r_1>0,\dots,r_N>0$,
where
$$
K=\frac1{A^{2N}}\prod_{j=1}^N N_j$$
is the (here positive) determinant of the (here diagonal) Jacobian matrix
$$\frac{N_1 r_1/A^2,\dots,N_N r_N/A^2}{\p(r_1,\dots,r_N)}
$$
of the transformation $(r_1,\dots,r_N)\mapsto(N_1 r_1/A^2,\dots,N_N r_N/A^2)$, which latter is inverse to the transformation $(r_1,\dots,r_N)\mapsto
(A^2s_1/N_1,\dots,A^2s_N/N_N)$.

So,
$P_{\ga_1,\dots,\ga_N}(r_1,\dots,r_N)=$
$$\frac1{(2A)^N}
\prod_{k=1}^N \left(
\frac{N_k}{A\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)} 
\exp\left(-\frac{N_k r_k + \mu_k^2 N_1r_1}{A^2\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)} \right)\right.$$
$$\left.\times I_0 \left(\frac{2\mu_k(N_1N_2r_1r_2)^{1/2}}
{A^2\sigma^2(1-\mu_k^2)}\right) 
\right) $$
for $r_1>0,\dots,r_N>0$.